# Proof that in a sequence of vectors of length N, the Nth vector must be zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, vectors, symmetric-polynomials

I have an assertion about a sequence of vectors which I have tested on a
computer but which I have been unable to prove. The assertion is that when
the vectors defined below are of length $N$, then the $N^{\text{th}}$ vector in the sequence must be zero.  Can anyone prove it?

The sequnce of vectors is defined as follows.  Denote the first vector in
the sequence by $\mathbf{v}=\left( v_{1},v_{2},\cdots v_{N},\right) $, where
the sum of the $v_{i}$  is zero, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{N}v_{i}=0
\end{equation}
Then define vectors $\mathbf{u}^{\left( 1\right) }\left( \mathbf{v}\right) $
, $\mathbf{u}^{\left( 2\right) }\left( \mathbf{v}\right) $, $...$recursively
as follows.  If the elements of $\mathbf{u}^{\left( q\right) }\left( 
\mathbf{v}\right) $ are $u_{i}^{\left( q\right) }$ for $1\leqslant
i\leqslant N$, then for $q=1$ define
\begin{equation}
u_{i}^{\left( 1\right) }=v_{i}
\end{equation}
and for $q\geqslant 2$ define
\begin{equation}
u_{i}^{\left( q\right) }=u_{i}^{\left( q-1\right) }v_{i}-\frac{1}{q}%
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}v_{j}u_{j}^{\left( q-1\right) }
\end{equation}
The assertion is that as long as the sum of the $v_{i}$ is zero, then for vectors $\mathbf{v}$ of length $N$, $u_{i}^{\left( N\right) }=0$ for all $i$.

The first few $u_{i}^{\left( q\right) }$ are as follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
u_{i}^{(1)}=v_{i} \\ 
u_{i}^{(2) }=v_{i}^{2}-\frac{1}{2}s_{2} \\ 
u_{i}^{(3)}=v_{i}^{3}-\frac{1}{2}v_{i}s_{2}-\frac{1}{3}s_{3} \\ 
u_{i}^{(4)}=v_{i}^{4}-\frac{1}{2}v_{i}^{2}s_{2}-\frac{1}{3}
v_{i}s_{3}-\frac{1}{4}\left( s_{4}-\frac{1}{2}s_{2}^{2}\right)  \\ 
u_{i}^{(5)}=v_{i}^{5}-\frac{1}{2}v_{i}^{3}s_{2}-\frac{1}{3}
v_{i}^{2}s_{3}-\frac{1}{4}v_{i}\left( s_{4}-\frac{1}{2}s_{2}^{2}\right) -
\frac{1}{5}\left( s_{5}-\frac{5}{6}s_{2}s_{3}\right)  \\ 
u_{i}^{(6)}=v_{i}^{6}-\frac{1}{2}v_{i}^{4}s_{2}-\frac{1}{3}%
v_{i}^{3}s_{3}-\frac{1}{4}v_{i}^{2}\left( s_{4}-\frac{1}{2}s_{2}^{2}\right) -
\frac{1}{5}v_{i}\left( s_{5}-\frac{5}{6}s_{2}s_{3}\right) -\frac{1}{6}\left(
s_{6}-\frac{1}{3}s_{3}^{2}+\frac{1}{8}s_{2}^{3}-\frac{3}{4}s_{2}s_{4}\right) \end{array}
\end{equation}
where the $s_{q}$ are the [power sum symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) defined by
\begin{equation}
s_{q}=\sum_{i}^{N}v_{i}^{q}
\end{equation}
The assertion is trivial for $N=1$, because if there is only one element in
the vector $v_{i}$, then since the sum of $v_{i}$ is zero then the single
element $v_{1}$ must be zero.

When $N=2$, then $v_{1}+v_{2}=0$ so $v_{1}=-v_{2}$ and  $%
s_{2}=2v_{1}^{2}=2v_{2}^{2}$, which again gives $u_{1}^{\left( 2\right)
}=u_{2}^{\left( 2\right) }=0$.

When $N=3$, then $v_{1}+v_{2}+v_{3}=0$ so
\begin{eqnarray*}
s_{3} &=&v_{1}^{3}+v_{2}^{3}+v_{3}^{3} \\
&=&v_{1}^{3}+v_{2}^{3}-\left(
v_{1}^{3}+3v_{1}^{2}v_{2}+3v_{1}v_{2}^{2}+v_{2}^{3}\right)  \\
&=&3v_{1}v_{2}v_{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
Then without loss of generality, consider $u_{i}^{\left( 3\right) }$ for $i=1
$ so
\begin{eqnarray}
u_{1}^{\left( 3\right) } &=&v_{1}^{3}-\frac{1}{2}v_{1}s_{2}-\frac{1}{3}s_{3}
\\
&=&v_{1}^{3}-\frac{1}{2}v_{1}\left( v_{1}^{2}+v_{2}^{2}+v_{3}^{2}\right)
-v_{1}v_{2}v_{3}  \notag \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}v_{1}\left( \left( v_{2}+v_{3}\right)
^{2}-v_{2}^{2}-v_{3}^{2}\right) -v_{1}v_{2}v_{3}  \notag \\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

Perhaps there's a recursive proof, but if so, I haven't been able to find
it.

**Note about symmetry:**  A comment mentioned symmetric polynomials.  Although each individual $%
u_{i}^{(q)}$ isn't symmetric in all the $\{v_{j}\}$, because of the
dependence on $v_{i}$, the vectors $\mathbf{u}^{(q)}$ are symmetric with
respect to changing the order of the $v_{j}$, i.e. they satisfy
$$\mathbf{M}^{ij}\mathbf{u}^{(q)}\left( \mathbf{v}\right) =\mathbf{u}%
^{(q)}\left( \mathbf{M}^{ij}\mathbf{v}\right)$$ where $\mathbf{M}^{ij}$ is the $N\times N$ matrix that switches the $i^{%
\text{th}}$ element with the $j^{\text{th}}$ element in a vector of length $N
$ with all other elements in the vector unchanged.

Comment: Try expressing $u_i^{(q)}$ in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials of $\{v_j\}$. I'm guessing but these are likely to collapse. In any case use them to construct a polynomial that all the $u_i^{(N)}$ satisfy. If it comes out as $x^N = 0$ you've won!

Comment: Thanks for leaving a comment @ScottBurns but $u_{i}^{(q)}$ isn't symmetric in all the $\{v_{j}\}$, because of the dependence on $v_{i}$. Doesn't that mean that $u_{i}^{(q)}$ can't be expressed in terms of symmetric polynomials in the $\{v_{j}\}$?

Comment: There's something like a Schur polynomial happening here. The clue is in the ${-1\over4} (s_4 - s_2^2)$ term for $u_i^{(4)}$. Please calculate the degree 5 terms for $u_i^{(5)}$. I'm going to guess them!
$$
{-1\over5} s_5 + {1\over6} s_2s_3
$$
Am I right?

Comment: Yes @ScottBurns you are right :-).  I've added $u_{i}^{(5)}$ and $u_{i}^{(6)}$ to the main question text.  I'm not familiar with Schur polynomials, does that help prove the assertion?

Comment: It may do. Schur polynomials generalise the relationships between various types of symmetric polynomial. You're unlikely to need them in complete generalisation, but Newton's identities may help. Check them out on wikipedia, in particular the section on expressing elementary polynomials as power sums. You'll find some very familiar looking terms :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does fall out using Newton's identities, much as I suspected in my first comment.

Newton's identity is pretty, if a little hard to take in:
$$
e_n = {1\over n!} \sum_{(a)\in S_n} |(a)| \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{a_i}
$$
where the sum is over the conjugacy classes of $S_n$, equivalently the partitions of $[n]$. The class $(a)$ is composed of $a_i$ $i$-cycles, for each $i$. $e_n$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $n$, and similarly $p_n$ is the power-sum polynomial.

We observe that in the expressions for $u_i^{(n)}$ the coefficient of $v_i^r$ matches the right-hand side of Newton's identity in $n-r$, by virtue of the initial condition that $p_1 = 0$. [This needs a little work to prove, but the pattern is very clear!]

So substituting into the expressions for $u_i^{(n)}$,
$$
u_i^{(n)} = \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^{(n-r)}e_{n-r} v_i^r
$$
If we view this as a polynomial in $v_i$, what are the roots? This is pretty trivial at $n=N$, as this is just the standard expression for the expansion of a product of linear terms. Therefore
$$
u_i^{(N)} = \prod_{j=1}^N (v_i - v_j) = 0
$$
And we are done :-)

Comment: Thanks Scott :-).  I had got as far as your penultimate equation, not proved, but I had noted that it was true for low N.  However, I hadn't worked out the factorisation in your final equation.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :-) I was thinking about this on a long drive today, and realised that there is a neater way of expressing the problem, which doesn't rely on the sum being zero. So

Comment: So start with a vector $v^{(0)}$ and let
$$
v^{(r)}_i = v^{(0)}_i v^{(r-1)}_i - {1\over r} \sum_j v^{(0)}_j v^{(r-1)}_j
$$
Then $v^{(N)}$ = 0

Comment: That's *almost* just the same recurrence relationship that I specified with $u_i^{(q)}$ relabeled as $v_i^{(r)}$.  In your notation, my relationship would be $$v_{i}^{(r)}=v_{i}^{(0)}v_{i}^{(r-1)}-\frac{1}{r+1}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}v_{j}^{(0)}v_{j}^{(r-1)}$$ where $\sum_j v_j^{(0)}=0$ implies $v_{i}^{(N-1)}=0$.  However, I tested your version on computer and I don't think it's true.

Comment: That's what I get for doing maths in the car :-) I did the wrong subtraction in my head...

Comment: I was trying to get the same reduction to having coefficients in $e_{n-r}$ without having $e_1=0$. I think I have it right this time:

Start with a vector $u$, and let $v_i^{(0)}=1$ $\forall i$. Then the iterative step is

$$
v_i^{(r)} = u_i v_i^{(r-1)} - {1\over r} \sum_j u_j v_j^{(r-1)}
$$

Comment: I tested your new version for $N=3$ on computer and it works :-).  FYI, for me this work is all about constructing the most general vector function of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ (or $\mathbf{u}$ in your last comment) that satisfies the symmetry condition that I put at the bottom of the original question.  In my case when $\sum_i v_i = 0$, then e.g. when $N=3$ the cubic terms $$\gamma_1 v_i^3+\gamma_2 v_i s_2+\gamma_3 s_3$$ contain a redundancy because $$v_i^3-\frac{1}{2}v_i s_2-\frac{1}{3}s_3=0  \text{  for all }i$$ So what is the most general polynomial form for each $N$ which has no redundancies?